# Place Javascript Variable within Razor Code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have one JavaScript function which adds a row into the table with the selected value in a text box. But how will i place the selected value inside the razor code ?

```
var val = document.getElementById("tags").value;
var strHtml2 = '@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.extraDoc.dr_name, new {Value="Place Val Here", @class = "input1", @readonly = true })';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible, because .NET MVC is server side code and is evaluated before being sent to the client, and javascript is Client side code which runs only once it is ON the client.

Actually you can do one thing you can get the element by using **Id**.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.extraDoc.dr_name, new {Value="Place Val Here", @class = "input1", @readonly = true })
```

Razor will generate id field for the TextBoxFor probably id will be something like this: `extraDoc_dr_name` (or) you can find it in browser developer tool.

then you can set it using javascript:

```
document.getElementById("extraDoc_dr_name").value = document.getElementById("tags").value;
```

Comment: If i wish to add the id dynamically , how should I do it. Like each time I add a row, id is something like "name"+count where count is a javascript var.

Comment: It is not a best practice, but you can set the id attribute using javascript `document.getElementById("extraDoc_dr_name").setAttribute("id","test")`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var val = document.getElementById("tags").value;
var strHtml2 = '@Model.extraDoc.dr_name'  ;
```

Update:

Now i understand what you are trying to archive.

No, you cannot mix js variable inside razor code. You can assing a razor value to a js variable, but not a js variable to a razor variable(afaik)

Comment: How can i dynamically generate ids for a razor textbox with a javascript variable then ?